# Weird issue with Azure SQL Database v12: the database is always slow on the first insert or delete execution, but not with V11

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-web-app-service

We are using MVC4, ASP.NET 4.5, Entity Framework 6.

When we used Azure SQL Database v11, initial record inserts and deletes via EF, worked fine and quickly. However now, on v12, I notice that initial inserts and deletes can be very slow, especially if we choose a new value when inserting. If we insert a new record with the same value, the response is rapid. The delay I am talking about can be about 30 on S1, 15 secs on S2, 7 secs on S3.

As I say, we never encountered this on v11.

Any ideas gratefully received.

EDIT1

Just been doing some diagnostics and it seems that a view that I was using now runs very slowly first time:

```
db.ExecuteStoreCommand("DELETE FROM Vw_Widget where Id={0}", ID);
```

Do I need to rejig views in anyway for Azure SQL Database v12?

EDIT2

Looking at the Code a little more I see that I have added a delete trigger to the View, so basically I have set up a view so I can use this trigger code in certain situations. I am now trying to take out the trigger code and run it from the app, which does run alot quicker. Perhaps this code should be a stored procedure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Definitely you need to do some diagnostics for your view to check the performance of your query and you may need to tune your query. The time measures you are saying is so high to perform any operation. Please make sure to do insert or deletes on your target tables and not views. The best practice is not to use views to insert or delete.

You can use views only in select statements.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have added EDIT2 in response to it.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem when make a migration of sql database v2 to v12.  Actually i was working with business model and I tried to migrate to S0.  The performance of the DB was not good.  After sometime i discover that dtu model has particular views to monitor what type of provison model do you need. If is on the first time the problem, probably your application are making a lot of queries to load data in memory and these can be affecting the performance of your CRUD statement.

SELECT end_time
     , (SELECT Max(v)
         FROM (VALUES (avg_cpu_percent)
                     , (avg_data_io_percent)
                     , (avg_log_write_percent)
       ) AS value(v)) AS [avg_DTU_percent]
FROM sys.dm_db_resource_stats
ORDER BY end_time DESC;

more information about that, can be found on these page:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-upgrade-server-portal/